# Device tree: Value out of range for 32-bit array element

Tags: memory, properties, tree, device, 32-bit

In my hardware I want to address 8GB RAM memory but compilation fails with error: "Value out of range for 32-bit array element". Is there any workaround that allow use 64bit numbers in memory property? I can't find binding file for this property in Documentation directory of kernel tree... Can anyone point me right place?

```
 memory@200000000 {
             device_type = "memory";
              /* 8G RAM */
              reg = <0x000000000 0x200000000 0x000000000 0x200000000>;
};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes the elements in the regions array (reg =) are 32bit but you can use 2x32bit to specify the size (like hi/low addresses).

So for a 8GB memory starting at 0x20000000 it should look like this:

```
  memory@200000000 {
                  device_type = "memory";
                   /* 8G RAM */
                   reg = <0x0 0x0000000020000000 0x00000001 0x00000000>,
                         <0x1 0x0000000000000000 0x00000001 0x00000000>;
 };
```

Where 0x00000001 0x00000000 actually represent the 4GB (0x1000000000) but written as 2x32bit values.